# What is the difference between On or Where in LEFT JOIN?

Tags: sql, left-join

What is the difference between the following pieces of SQL code:

```
select count(*)
from A
left join B
on a.id = b.id
where a.status = 2 and
b.id is NULL
```

and

```
select count(*)
from A
left join B
on a.id = b.id
and a.status =2
where b.id is NULL
```

? I read this : [Semantic difference between join queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677613/semantic-difference-between-join-queries) but I still don't know which one is better to use

> I have spend the past hour reading this and grasping it all answers added value but I understood the code example together with "never encountered this" the best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewriting the 2 queries without the `LEFT JOIN / IS NULL` so it's obvious that they can return different data sets in certain cases:

```
---Query 1

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM a
WHERE a.status = 2
  AND NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM b
        WHERE a.id = b.id
      )
```

and

```
---Query 2

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM a
WHERE NOT ( a.status = 2
        AND EXISTS 
            ( SELECT *
              FROM b
              WHERE a.id = b.id
            )
          )

--- or:

---Query 2
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM a
WHERE a.status <> 2
   OR NOT EXISTS 
      ( SELECT *
        FROM b
        WHERE a.id = b.id
      )
```

Comment: I understand, so query 1 is better. Am I correct to assume that if it was "B.status=2" then it would be in example 1 of your query2 in the exist () clause so (SELECT * from b WHERE a.id a= b.id AND b.status=2) ?

Comment: Query 1 and 2 are different, they return different results. Query 1 is not better, but it's more common. I have never encountered a Query2 type in real situations.

Comment: Yes, to your second question, a `b.status=2` condition changes things dramatically. That is very common situation (and to have it working with a Left Join, you put that condition in the `ON` part).

Comment: +1 this is a clear way of representing the query. The `left join where null` style queries can be very confusing!

Comment: @dotjoe: Yes. Even more when you add a condition of the left table at the `ON` clause.

Comment: and even more when that condition is only related to the main table

Answer (score 10):

It is key to how LEFT joins are used, one will filter the result out, the other will merely fail the LEFT join, preserving data from the LEFT side of the JOIN.

(1) left join B on a.id = b.id
**where a.status = 2**

Ignoring other filters, this says to LEFT JOIN against the table B, so, "try to join to table B using the condition `a.id=b.id`".
If you can't make a match, keep the records on the left table (i.e. A).  Subsequent to that, on the remaining records, FILTER out (i.e. REMOVE) records that do not match `a.status=2`

(2) left join B
**on** a.id = b.id **and a.status =2**

Ignoring other filters, this says to LEFT JOIN against the table B on 2 conditions, so, "try to join to table B on both conditions `a.id = b.id and a.status =2`".  If you get no records from B given both conditions (even if one is unrelated to B), keep the record from A anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The difference is where the condition is logically evaluated, which in turn can affect the result set.

In your examples (reformatted), you have:

**Example 1**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON a.id = b.id
 WHERE a.status = 2 AND b.id is NULL
```

**Example 2**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON a.id = b.id AND a.status = 2
 WHERE b.id is NULL
```

In the first case, the LEFT JOIN is applied and a result set is generated; this is then filtered with the two conditions in the WHERE clause.

In the second case, the LEFT JOIN is formed with the filter condition on `a.status`, and in some circumstances could alter the result set from the LEFT JOIN.  This result set is then filtered with the main WHERE clause.

Example 2 is essentially equivalent to:

**Example 2A**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT * FROM A WHERE a.status = 2) AS A
  LEFT JOIN B ON a.id = b.id
 WHERE b.id is NULL
```

With some queries (but probably not this one), the difference can matter.

---

Let's try to create some simple sample data:

```
Table A               Table B
id    status          id
4     2               1
5     3
```

Example 1 will have an intermediate result set:

```
a.id   a.status   b.id
4      2          null
5      3          null
```

and the WHERE clause eliminates the second row.

Example 2 will have an intermediate result set:

```
a.id   a.status   b.id
4      2          null
```

In this example, the net result is the same, and I haven't been able to come up with data that doesn't end up the same.

If the query condition that is moved around is on the outer-joined table and is more complex than simple equality, then you can see an effect.

Comment: I think example 2 would be equivalent to that only if it was an inner join.

Comment: The 'that' in your comment is ambiguous - assuming you are referring to the variation with `FROM (SELECT * FROM A WHERE a.status = 2) AS A` as 'that' (let's call it Example 2A), then I challenge you to come up with a sample data set where there is a difference between Example 2 and Example 2A.

Comment: @jonathan: With your dataset, Example 2 will have an intermediate (and final) result set with 2 rows, not 1. And example 2A, will have a result set of 1 row.

Comment: My reading is that `Example 1` is equivalent to `Example 2A`.

Comment: I don't see how you can move `a.status = 2` from the left join criteria into the subquery and it have it be equal. Wouldn't example 2 intermediate results have 2 rows while example 2A only one row? If anything your example 2A is equal to example 1?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is easier to follow:

```
SELECT id
  FROM A
 WHERE status = 2
EXCEPT
SELECT id
  FROM B;
```

In the unlikely event you are only interested in the cardinality of the result:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM ( SELECT id
           FROM A
          WHERE status = 2
         EXCEPT
         SELECT id
           FROM B ) AS DT1;
```